Special stairs of infinites and infinitesimals
I’m trying to create a scale of infinites and infinitesimals within a beamer slide. The scale should have varying heights.

Some of the heights are dashed,

and the horizontal step length changes depending on the functions that are on each step. Additionally there is also a base with the explanation of the functions:

Here there is another image:

I’ve managed to develop a basic code, but I’d appreciate your help to refine and improve it.
Here is a related, recent question, tagged with nicematrix:
How to draw this matrix with stairs and submatrices?
My MWE:
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Scala degli infiniti}
% Define scale parameters using \newcommand
\newcommand{\stepHeight}{1}  % Height of each step
\newcommand{\stepDepth}{2}   % Depth (horizontal length) of each step
\newcommand{\numSteps}{8}    % Number of steps

% Define the functions to associate with the steps
\newcommand{\fA}{\ln(\ln(x))}
\newcommand{\fB}{\log(x), \log_a(x), a>0, a\neq 1}
\newcommand{\fC}{x^{1/2}}
\newcommand{\fD}{x}
\newcommand{\fE}{x^n}
\newcommand{\fF}{2^x}
\newcommand{\fG}{3^x}
\newcommand{\fH}{n!}
\newcommand{\fI}{n^n}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Draw the steps (lines)
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\numSteps} {
    % Draw the horizontal step (tread)
    \draw[thick] (\i*\stepDepth, \i*\stepHeight) -- ({(\i+1)*\stepDepth}, {\i*\stepHeight});
    % Draw the vertical step (riser)
    \draw[thick] ({(\i+1)*\stepDepth}, {\i*\stepHeight}) -- ({(\i+1)*\stepDepth}, {(\i+1)*\stepHeight});
}

% Position the functions slightly above each horizontal tread
\node at ({\stepDepth/2}, {0.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fA$};
\node at ({1.5*\stepDepth}, {1.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fB$};
\node at ({2.5*\stepDepth}, {2.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fC$};
\node at ({3.5*\stepDepth}, {3.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fD$};
\node at ({4.5*\stepDepth}, {4.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fE$};
\node at ({5.5*\stepDepth}, {5.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fF$};
\node at ({6.5*\stepDepth}, {6.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fG$};
\node at ({7.5*\stepDepth}, {7.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fH$};
\node at ({8.5*\stepDepth}, {8.2*\stepHeight}) {$\fI$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



what do you want to change exactly? to stop the label clashing with the lines of the steps? to add something? why is this tagged nicematrix? what's the relationship between the functions and the depths/widths exactly?

@cfr I included nicematrix because I think the scales can also be created using matrices. I had seen something about nicematrix a few days ago. I would like the code to produce exactly the two initial images. My code isn't good.

well, but aren't there lots of ways you could do it?

to the close-voter: why?

@cfr Don't worry. It happens.

oh, I know. however, I've discovered that very occasionally, such questions actually get responses. not often, but just now and again.

This is a preliminary solution. It has one main problem in that the lines do not connect properly, despite the math appearing to be correct.
The scales are chosen manually for the figure to fit the page, as are the shifts.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Scala degli infiniti}
\newcommand{\fA}{\ln(\ln(x))}
\newcommand{\fB}{\log(x), \log_a(x), a>0, a\neq 1}
\newcommand{\fC}{x^{1/2}}
\newcommand{\fD}{x}
\newcommand{\fE}{x^n}
\newcommand{\fF}{2^x}
\newcommand{\fG}{3^x}
\newcommand{\fH}{n!}
\newcommand{\fI}{n^n}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,xshift=-1cm,yshift=-4cm,yscale=0.8]
\begin{scope}[scale=0.84]
\pgflowlevelsynccm
\coordinate (prev) at (0,0); 

\foreach
[count=\i from 1] 
\function in {\fA, \fB, \fC, \fD, \fE, \fF, \fG, \fH, \fI} 
{
    \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=west] (func\i) at (prev) {\Large $\function$};
    \pgfmathparse{random(0,100)/50+0.3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrandom}{\pgfmathresult}
    \coordinate (prev) at ($(func\i.east) + (0.5,\myrandom)$);
    \ifnum\i<9
        \draw 
        ($(func\i.south west) + (-1ex,-1ex)$) -- 
        ($(func\i.south east) + (-1ex,-1ex) + (0.5,0)$) -- 
        ++(0,\myrandom);
    \else
        \draw 
        ($(func\i.south west) + (-1ex,-1ex)$) -- 
        ($(func\i.south east) + (1ex,-1ex)$);
    \fi
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Edit:
The problem with the lines not connecting is the vertical lengths of the nodes, which cause the eastern anchors to be misaligned. I fixed this by adding a vertical strut which exceeds the height of the tallest node. I was able to add dashed lines using a conditional which is based on a random \pgfmathparse.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Scala degli infiniti}
\newcommand{\fA}{\ln(\ln(x))}
\newcommand{\fB}{\log(x), \log_a(x), a>0, a\neq 1}
\newcommand{\fC}{x^{1/2}}
\newcommand{\fD}{x}
\newcommand{\fE}{x^n}
\newcommand{\fF}{2^x}
\newcommand{\fG}{3^x}
\newcommand{\fH}{n!}
\newcommand{\fI}{n^n}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,xshift=-1cm,yshift=-4cm,yscale=0.8]
\begin{scope}[scale=0.84]
\pgflowlevelsynccm

\coordinate (prev) at (0,0); 
\foreach
[count=\i from 1] 
\function in {\fA, \fB, \fC, \fD, \fE, \fF, \fG, \fH, \fI} 
{
    \node[anchor=west] (func\i) at (prev) {\rule{0ex}{3ex}$\function$};
    \pgfmathparse{random(0,100)/50+0.3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrandom}{\pgfmathresult}
    \coordinate (prev) at ($(func\i.east) + (0.5,\myrandom)$);
    \ifnum\i<9
        \pgfmathparse{random(0,100)>50}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \draw 
            ($(func\i.south west) + (-1ex,-1ex)$) -- 
            ($(func\i.south east) + (-1ex,-1ex) + (0.5,0)$) -- 
            ++(0,\myrandom);
        \else
            \draw 
            ($(func\i.south west) + (-1ex,-1ex)$) -- 
            ($(func\i.south east) + (-1ex,-1ex) + (0.5,0)$);
            \draw[dashed]
            ($(func\i.south east) + (-1ex,-1ex) + (0.5,0)$) -- 
            ++(0,\myrandom);
        \fi
    \else
        \draw 
        ($(func\i.south west) + (-1ex,-1ex)$) -- 
        ($(func\i.south east) + (1ex,-1ex)$);
    \fi
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Edit (@jlab)
The (prev) coordinate is defined at the end of each stair, allowing the next step to be correctly connected. I also set line cap=rect for a better rendering.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Scala degli infiniti}
\newcommand{\fA}{\ln(\ln(x))}
\newcommand{\fB}{\log(x), \log_a(x), a>0, a\neq 1}
\newcommand{\fC}{x^{1/2}}
\newcommand{\fD}{x}
\newcommand{\fE}{x^n}
\newcommand{\fF}{2^x}
\newcommand{\fG}{3^x}
\newcommand{\fH}{n!}
\newcommand{\fI}{n^n}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,xshift=-1cm,yshift=-4cm,yscale=0.8, line cap=rect]
\begin{scope}[scale=0.84]
\pgflowlevelsynccm

\coordinate (prev) at (0,0);
\foreach
[count=\i from 1]
\function in {\fA, \fB, \fC, \fD, \fE, \fF, \fG, \fH, \fI}
{
    \node[anchor=south west] (func\i) at (prev) {$\function$};
    \pgfmathparse{random(0,100)/50+0.3}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrandom}{\pgfmathresult}
    \ifnum\i<9
        \pgfmathparse{random(0,100)>50}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
            \draw
            ($(func\i.south west)$) --
            ($(func\i.south east) + (0.5,0)$) --
            ++(0,\myrandom)
            coordinate (prev);
        \else
            \draw
            ($(func\i.south west)$) --
            ($(func\i.south east) + (0.5,0)$);
            \draw[dashed]
            ($(func\i.south east) + (0.5,0)$) --
            ++(0,\myrandom)
            coordinate (prev);
        \fi
    \else
        \draw
        (func\i.south west) -- (func\i.south east);
    \fi
}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



You've been very kind, and I really appreciate it. Thank you again. But some of the edges are not perfect, or am I wrong? (+1). Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

@Sebastiano You are correct. It would seem that I did the math correctly, and still the edges are not connecting. I do not know the cause of this issue.

You don't have to worry at all. I appreciate you.

There are still some small vertical alignment issues, I just can't figure out how to overcome them right now.

I don't understand why all the functions appear squished. Also, is it easy to create the dashed horizontal line under the fraction? Thank you so much.

@Sebastiano I deliberately shrunk the diagram so it would fit on the screen (using scale and \pgflowlevelsynccm), so that is probably why it appears squished. Let me see if I can get that horizontal line for ya.

Maybe you can reconnect the lines by defining coordinate (prev) just after ++(0,\myrandom), using anchor=south west instead of anchor=west for (func\i). With this ways you always start drawing from the last position.

@jlab I tried implementing this, but I can't seem to get it to work. If you can, feel free to edit the answer - a solution would be interesting, but not necessary.

I posted a proposal. Feel free to edit, amend or delete it.

Maybe this can be drawn with the chain TikZ library. Define for example a node style
stair/.style 2 args={
  on chain,
  above=#1 of \tikzchainprevious.south east,
  anchor=south west,
  draw=none,
  rectangle,
  append after command={
    (\tikzchainprevious.south east) edge [stair line, #2] (\tikzlastnode.south west)
    (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[stair line] (\tikzlastnode.south east)
  }
}

taking two arguments

#1 is the stair height;
#2 is the vertical line style.

You can set default values for the arguments
stair/.default={4mm}{},

and define the style stair line used by default
stair line/.style={thin},

Example:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\tikzset{
  stair line/.style={thin},
  stair/.style 2 args={
    on chain,
    above=#1 of \tikzchainprevious.south east,
    anchor=south west,
    draw=none,
    rectangle,
    append after command={
      (\tikzchainprevious.south east) edge [stair line, #2] (\tikzlastnode.south west)
      (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[stair line] (\tikzlastnode.south east)
    }
  },
  stair/.default={4mm}{},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Scala degli infiniti}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    start chain,
    font=\scriptsize,
  ]

  \node (A) [on chain] {}; % origin
  \node[stair]{$\ln(\ln(x))$};
  \node[stair]{$\log(x), \log_a(x), a>0, a\neq 1$};
  \node (B) [stair={1cm}{dashed}]{$x^{1/3}$};
  \node[stair]{$x^{1/2}$};
  \node[stair]{$x, 2x$};
  \node[stair]{$x^2$};
  \node (C) [stair={1cm}{dashed}]{$x^n$};
  \node[stair]{$2^x$};
  \node[stair]{$3^x$};
  \node (D) [stair={1cm}{dashed}]{$n!$};
  \node (E) [stair={0.75cm}{dashed}]{$n^n$};

  \draw[
    densely dashed,
    transform canvas={yshift=-0.5cm},
    every node/.style={anchor=base, inner sep=2pt, yshift=-0.25ex}
  ]
  (A)
  -- (A-|B) node[midway, fill=white]{logaritmi}
  -- (A-|C) node[midway, fill=white]{potenze}
  -- (A-|D) node[midway, fill=white]{esp.}
  -- (A-|E.east) node[midway, fill=white]{fat.};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}



You've been very kind as well. I don't have any votes available at the moment. Your answer puts me in a difficult position. I don't know who to give the green check to. :(

@Sebastiano I think jlab's solution is better because the lines connect properly, and  you can choose when to add the dashed lines. Feel free to give them the check :-)

@Jasper Even though the answer is better, you took a lot of time.

@Sebastiano That is true, but I have fun doing these things. Feel free to give the tick to jlab, I got lots of upvotes yesterday anyway :-)

@Jasper I know you've received positive votes .

@Sebastiano It's not very important. It was just for the fun of finding a different method. And wait. You can always get another answer.

@jlab Thank you again for your precious contribution.

With nicematrix.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Scala degli infiniti}
$\begin{NiceMatrix}
  &&&&&&&& n^n \\
  &&&&&&& n! \\
  &&&&&& 3^x \rule{0pt}{1cm} \\
  &&&&& 2^x \\
  &&&& x^n \\
  &&& x \\
  && x^{1/2} \rule{0pt}{1cm} \\
  & \log(x), \log_a(x), a > 0, a \ne 1 \rule{0pt}{1cm} \\
  \ln(\ln(x)) \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (10-|1) -| (9-|2) -- (9-|3) ; 
    \draw [dashed] (9-|3) -- (8-|3) ; 
    \draw (8-|3) -- (8-|4) ; 
    \draw [dashed] (8-|4) -- (7-|4) ; 
    \draw (7-|4) -| (6-|5) -| (5-|6) -| (4-|7) -- (4-|8) ; 
    \draw [dashed] (4-|8) -- (3-|8) ; 
    \draw (3-|8) -- (3-|9) ; 
    \draw [dashed] (3-|9) -- (2-|9) ; 
    \draw (2-|9) -- (2-|10) ; 
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}$
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thank you so much for the excellent answer! The solution with nicematrix is really interesting and very helpful.
